# Regex special characters by ascii

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to use regex for my password validation that include special characters at least one.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

```
export const passwordValidation = password => {
  const regPassword = /^(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/

  return regPassword.test(password)
}
```

I tried this way but I think this isn't good way.
Is there other way to check all special characters by ascii code except alphanumeric ?

Comment: What are the requirements on your password?

Comment: Note: All of the characters you've used in your regex's character class are ASCII.

Comment: This will ignore `a-zA-Z0-9` across the `0x20-0x7e` ascii character range. If any of the character is within the range and is not `a-zA-Z0-9`, it'll return a match. `(?![a-zA-Z0-9])[\x20-\x7e]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to define what a "special" character is. Do you mean anything not in the range A-Z (English alphabet)? A-Z and 0-9? Something else? Then you either use a character class listing the ones you want, which is what you've done, or a *negated* class saying you want something *other than* what's in the class:

```
return /^(?=.*?[^a-z0-9]).{8,}$/i.test(password);
//              ^---- negated
```

Comment: @kkangil - No worries, glad that helped. Odd request: Would you un-accept the answer please? Thanks.